# Подключения класса

Tags: php, curl

есть [класс работы с curl](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class), не как не могу подключить нужный класс что бы работать с методами на денвер ну вот как подключить класс? что то не нашел в архиве.

Comment: То есть [Quick start](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class#quick-start-and-examples) вы не нашли?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там написано конечно, но на архиве нет файл autoload.php запускаю Examples на денвер и сразу ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (Инструкция для [Windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows))

Выполните `composer require php-curl-class/php-curl-class`

У вас появиться новая папка ’vendor’ в которой будет находиться ваша библиотека. Так же там находиться файл `autoload.php`

Остальные действия читайте после [Quick Start and Examples](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class#quick-start-and-examples)

Comment: Как правильно установить а то у меня ошибка: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in Z:\home\curl.tj\www\examples\put.php on line 2`

Comment: После чего у вас возникает эта ошибка?

Comment: перед `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` делаю так   `$ composer require php-curl-class/php-curl-class` это естественно ошибка ) просто не знаю как установит.